# remove img's parent tag and still leave the img

Tags: jquery, html, css

Currently I have

```
<p>
  <img src="" />
</p>
```

How can I remove an p tag that's wrapping an img tag?

So i can get just..

```
<img src="" />
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use

```
$('p > img').unwrap('<p />');
```

This will remove all p's around img. You should use a `class or id` to do this for a specific image.

More on [`.unwrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/)

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/AhHQz/

Comment: @Reuben, check the demo added.

Comment: oh I already got it working @Joy :) Just waiting for stack to let me accept.. THanks!

Comment: There can only be one `<p>` tag around the `<img>` to be semantically valid HTML (block level elements can't be nested within a `<p>` tag), so this is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$('#id_of_image').unwrap('<p />');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
  var $img = $('img'),
        $p = $('p');

  $p.after($img).remove()
});
```

Or just use unwrap() as above